# Assign user to group available even though not allowed? (Craft v3)

Tags: craft3, users, control-panel, permissions, user-groups

Working my way through the CMS to learn in more detail I'm currently at the users / permissions parts of the CMS. Here I just bumped into the following thing I don't understand:

I have a Users Group called 'Content Creators' having these permissions:

[image: Content Creators group permissions]

One user, being inside this 'Content Creators' group is logged in in the CMS. But for some reason still is allowed to assign and un-assign other users to the 'Content Creators' group. Even though this is not allowed as 'Assign users to "Content Creators"' isn't checked and therefore I would expect this to be prohibited in the group he's in.

[image: User is allowed to assign other users to the "Content Creators" group]

I don't get why this user is allowed to assign other users to the Content Creators group even though he is not allowed to do this.

The 'Assign users to "Content Creators"' is disabled in the user-specific permissions of the logged in user too, so it's not overwritten in the personal user settings.

Could anybody here please explain me why he is still allowed to do this?

Comment: Same issue, although I have 2 groups. I tick one group but not the other, but that user can still assign to that group even though it's not ticked. Is it because they themselves are in the group that is un-ticked?